# How to get back to Nomachine version 3 or getting version 4 to work?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, versions, nx, freenx

I recently upgraded from Lubuntu 12.10 to Lubuntu 14.04.

In doing that, I messed up with my apps and had to install the new version of Nomachine NX CLIENT (version 4).
Sadly, this version is giving me a big headache! The host at work is still using the 3.xx version and the connection doesn't work as it should.

I followed the instruction on NoMachine website to connect from a client V.4 to a server V3.x, I managed to connect to the server and to open a session, but I can't type anything!
I am stuck at the lockscreen stage, and can't type the password as NX seems to not recognise any input from the keyboard (but I can move the mouse).

I would be grateful if anybody can suggest a solution for that OR if there is a way to get the .deb file for a 3.x version of NX.
That was not perfect, but worked perfectly!

Thanks

Comment: I found a school in Germany offering the download for the 3.5 version. I solved my problem but would be happy to know if someone managed to properly configure nomachine4 on lubuntu